# Set passed value in my ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have two independent classes that model my tables. First when a new user is created, the user does not have a record in the certificate tables. So in the view for the certificates I have added a button to add certificates details for  this new user. 
 This is my code for the user view: I omitted the paging/search and filter code to make it simple

```
public ActionResult Index()
var recipients = from s in db.User
                         select s;
 return View(recipients.ToList());
```

This is the details view showing related data:

```
   public ViewResult Details(int id)
   {

   var certificateDetails = db.Certificate.Where(p => p.ID == id);
   return View(certificateDetails);
   }
```

Adding a new user means also adding a new certificates details. I want when a user clicks details for the a particular user if those details aint around to be redirected to a create certificate view with both User.ID and CertificateID set. In fact CertificateID is AI but ID from User is foreign key. 
I would have used Fluent API but am not good with it either so have to handle this seemingly small challenge in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want it so that when you view Details(), if the certificate details don't exist, then redirect to a page to create them?

Just check whether or not the entity exists. If it doesn't, return a [RedirectToAction()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) and pass whatever data you need in the route data collection.

```
public ViewResult Details(int id)
{
    var certificateDetails = db.Certificate.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == id);

    if (certificateDetails == null)
        return RedirectToAction("Create", "Certificate", new { userId = id });

    return View(certificateDetails);
}
```

You'll also need to create a Certificate controller with a Create() action.

Comment: I have Certificate controller, will edit my question to reflect that. I am using POCO  classes i.e code first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? If you have the Certificate controller, then all you need to do is redirect to it. Also you should accept some of your old questions, you'll get a better response rate.

Comment: Thanks for the added suggestion and answer. That change from where to SingleOrDefault has created problems in my sorting code when  the if statement is false.  it can not accept OrderBy.

Comment: SingleOrDefault() just returns a single object matching the criteria, or null if it doesn't exist. If more than one object matches the criteria, it throws an exception. You can change it to any database query you want. The problem with just calling Where() is it doesn't actually execute the query. So .Single(u => u.Id == id) is analogous to .Where(u => u.Id == id).Single();

Comment: How then do I let the else statement have a list not a single object?

Comment: whats happening is my view is throwing an exception when the table is not null saying Sequence contains more than one element.

Comment: It's because Single() throws an exception if there's more than one element that matches. You need to change it to ToList() if you want to load a collection. The Single() stuff isn't related to the question you asked, it was just what I used in my answer. You can change it to whatever query you want.